# Deploying Flexible VM Node.js hangs on Updating Service

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

When deploying our app with "gcloud app deploy" (which is a node.js flexible app engine app) we get stuck with the following command (after it pushes to the images)

> Updating service [default]...-

Its stuck there and we have no idea why. It did not do this initially, and now it takes 5 minutes to deploy any app. Is there anyway to speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your question. Could you post your configuration files? The more information we have, the easier it is to help you.

Comment: We'd love to help resolve this, but we need more information to do so!